# Tkz-fct Package Error -- I can't find file `tikzlibrary'.

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-collection

I tried to install and use the new `Tkz-fct` package.
The installation was OK, MikTex Package Manager says that I've
successfully installed the package but if I try the most easy example from
the `userguide` (from 20. January 2011) I got the message:

```
! I can't find file `tikzlibrary'.
```

and no file is produced...

Could anyone help me?
Thank much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that at least TikZ/PGF 2.10 is installed on your system. This is required for tkz-fct. If necessary, update TikZ/PGF using the MiKTeX package manager.

Comment: @user3097: You can check the version by added `\listfiles` to your preamble and look at listing in the output or the log file.

Comment: @Stefan -- Now I made a total update in MikTeX. I can draw tikzpictures, but there won't be any curve (function) produced. I just get the Warning: Package pgf Warning: Plot data file `LaTeX1.tkzfct.table' not found.

Comment: @Daniel: ensure that the update of MiKTeX also brings the latest TikZ/pgf. Is it the case? Otherwise update specifically the pgf/TikZ package after that distribution update. If the problem persists, please add a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to your question.

Comment: @Stefan
in MikTeX Package manager I see a package named pgf.
It is packaged on 2010-11-01
I installed it on 2011-02-13

But I don't find any packages named pgf/tikz, or tikz. What I can see are only: tikz-3dplot, tikz-qtree, tikz-timing, tikz-inet

and tkz-tab, tkz-euclide, tkz-base, tkz-fct, tkz-orm, tkz-linknodes, tkz-doc. So theese are the Packages I see in the package manager after filtering the name tikz and tkz.

I think I don't really understand how should I make an update ordinary... :(

Comment: pgf is the name of the MiKTeX package, you've got the [current version](http://miktex.org/packages/pgf) now. Try to post a minimal example which produces the problem.

Comment: Each Example from documentation tkz-fct 1.13c works without ploting the curves. The following is an example from the french userguide \documentclass{scrartcl} \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} \usepackage{tkz-fct} \begin{document} \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25] \tkzInit[xmin=-5,xmax=5,ymax=2] \tkzGrid \tkzAxeXY \tkzFct[color=red]{2*x**2/(x**2+1)} \end{tikzpicture} \end{document} and the warning: 

Package pgf Warning: Plot data file `LaTeX1.tkzfct.table' not found. on input line 9.

and after the warning:

...

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:

Comment: Do you have gnuplot installed?

Comment: @Jan -- That's a good quastion. I don't know. In the package Manager I can see gnuplottex installed at 2010-11-14. I haven't known, that I should do anyting with gnuplot. Any idea?

Comment: I don't think MikTeX includes gnuplot, I believe you need to install that separately.  The tkz-fct manual mentions installation of gnuplot on windows on page 12.  You can download gnuplot at http://www.gnuplot.info/, you will have to ask somebody who uses Windows for help with that, though, I cannot make head or tail of it. There seem to be several versions, I don't know which one you want, and I have no idea how to install them.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of this package. You need pgf 2.1 and gnuplot if you want to work with `tkz-fct`.
 I think your problem comes from gnuplot. I'm not a great expert of MikTeX but I explain in the documentation how to install gnuplot on MikTeX (but sorry, the documentation is only in French actually).

1. You need to install gnuplot (I think you need to rename `wgnuplot` to  `gnuplot`)
2. You need to indicate the path for gnuplot for example if gnuplot is in `C:\gnuplot` then you need to add `C:\gnuplot\bin\`  in the environment variables (something like this but I'm not an expert of Windows also .. generally I'm not an expert!!)
3. Now you need to add the option `--enable-write18` to the compilation script (sometimes this option is `--shell-escape`). I think you can find an answer for all these kinds of problems.